# Can GoogleApps exist with Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, g-suite, windows-server-2003

I am looking at the next step in our Groupware solutions.

Rather got with a conventional add a new MS Server/MS Exchange to allow for growth and expanding offices.

Could an Office operate with both an existing Exchange server setup and migrate a portion of mailboxes to the GoogleApps platform?

I want to see if the we could use the GoogleApps for managers and larger mailboxes, and leave a large amount of small mailboxes on the existing hardware that is configured for Exchange/outlook?

Can the two co-exist in an longterm configuration, where they can 'play nice' together?  Is there any options that would allow for for this and would this have limitations?  Such as the Free/busy connectors (Calendaring)?

Is there any pitfalls for this type of design?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use both -- see [this](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96855) document on dual-delivery options.

Comment: The delivery sounds great for the email side of things.  That would allow to offload the multi-GB mailboxes.  Can the Exchange sync the other Groupware functions as Calender/Free-busy between the GoogleApp users and exchange users?

Comment: I believe they'd need to be running the Google Calendar Sync desktop tool that would pull/push Google calendar changes into Exchange via each user's Outlook, for whomever is running this sync tool:
http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955

Comment: So from that link that would sync the Google Calendar to the Outlook.  Can the GoogleApp user have their Calendar to be able to be viewed by people that are on the locally hosted Exchange server.  Or is that something that would be setup on a per-user/group basis.

Comment: The Google users would still need an Exchange profile in their Outlook, but once their Google Calendar's data is in Outlook, it could be shared out like a "normal" Outlook/Exchange calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do what you want (see the link supplied by [gravyface](https://serverfault.com/questions/131616/can-googleapps-exist-with-exchange-2003/131622#131622)), but in my opinion it would be a mistake.  You will not like managing the dual-delivery, and your successor will curse your name.  You will have lots of little problems with syncing, calendars, invitations, etc. **If you want to go to Google, go with everybody.** That often makes a lot of sense.

You are better off finding a good [archiving](https://serverfault.com/search?q=email+archiving) solution, finding other means to manage the mailbox sizes (e.g. auto-archive to PST controlled by GPO), or upgrading to Exchange 2010, which has far fewer problems dealing with large mailboxes.